# Flutter: querying firebase realtime database data list with streambuilder error

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-streambuilder

iam trying to show list of data using StreamBuilderbut when i run this code it give me an error:

[image: error image here]

[image: database image here]

i am fallowing [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4XwkQcNCQs&t=315s&ab_channel=TheTechBrothers) and i am trying to show data list i need to do this using streambuilder

```
DatabaseReference starCountRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('/Shop/qw1234/Inventory/');

 Expanded(child:StreamBuilder(
            stream: starCountRef.onValue,
            builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<DatabaseEvent> snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                     Map<dynamic, dynamic> map =
                            snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as dynamic;
                        List<dynamic> list = [];
                        list.clear();
                        list = map.values.toList();
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('data'),
                      );
                    });
              }else{
return Text("no");
              }

            },
          )
          )
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content such as error messages. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys in your database are sequential numeric value (i.e. `1`, `2`, `3`), which the Firebase SDK interprets as the data being an array and thus exposing it as a `List` to your Flutter code.

So the proper way to get the values is:

```
List list = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as List;
```

Note that the list will not have any item at index 0, was that is missing in your source data too.

In general, it's recommended to *not* use such sequential numeric keys in Firebase, as it results in counterintuitive behavior at times. For more on this, and how to properly store lists of data in Firebase, see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).